# Adding div element to the page each time meets between start and end date within object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create div element in the page for each object within an array where todays date is between start and end date parameters, would be very thankful for any help.
The idea is to create and show event boxes for each respective day that are scheduled for that day using summary information for each event stored in an array as an object.

```js
var $todaysdate = new Date();
var $fullyear = $todaysdate.getFullYear();
var $month = $todaysdate.getMonth();
var $day = $todaysdate.getDate();
var $finaltoday = new Date($fullyear, $month, $day).toDateString();

var eventyz = [{
  startDate: new Date("2020-4-15").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-4-27").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info 1"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info 2"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info 3"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info4"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info5"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info6"
}];

eventyz.forEach(function MyDumbFunction(item) {
  if (Date.parse($finaltoday) <= Date.parse(item.startDate) && Date.parse($finaltoday) >=  
    Date.parse(item.endDate)) {
    $(".tttt").append("<div class='red_block'></div>");
  }
});
```

```css
.jigle {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.red_block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 id="kk"></h1>
<div class="tttt"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I added an executable snippet in to the question containing your code. Check the error in the console - you've got  two random backtick characters in the code causing the problem

Comment: Hi, the code doesnt work for some reason. I dont understand where could be the issue. It doesnt create any elements.

Comment: backticks removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison's are backwards.  You did less than start range and larger than end range.

```js
var $todaysdate = new Date();
var $fullyear = $todaysdate.getFullYear();
var $month = $todaysdate.getMonth();
var $day = $todaysdate.getDate();
var $finaltoday = new Date($fullyear, $month, $day).toDateString();

var eventyz = [{
  startDate: new Date("2020-4-15").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-4-27").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info 1"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info 2"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-4-28").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info 3"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info4"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info5"
}, {
  startDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  endDate: new Date("2020-5-4").toDateString(),
  summary: "Info6"
}];

eventyz.forEach(function MyDumbFunction(item) {
  if (Date.parse($finaltoday) >= Date.parse(item.startDate) && Date.parse($finaltoday) <=  
    Date.parse(item.endDate)) {
    $(".tttt").append("<div class='red_block'></div>");
  }
});
```

```css
.jigle {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.red_block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 id="kk"></h1>
<div class="tttt"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you mate! quite stupid mistake from my side :)